# Headphones with static noise

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 on my laptop, which already has Windows 10 installed, so I am dual-booting.

The problem is that I am getting static noise (or white noise - not sure how you call it) when using the headphones only. The problem seems to go away when in MUTE. Everything is up to date and all drivers are working fine.

I do not have that problem when running Windows 10.

I have already tried `alsamixer`, but it didn't work. Switching to pulse equalizer doesn't solve the problem either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Headphones white noise? Ubuntu 16.04.1](http://askubuntu.com/questions/861214/headphones-white-noise-ubuntu-16-04-1)

Comment: Yes. Didn´t solved with the other post.

Comment: Give it some time for an answer.  Don't post the same question multiple times.

Comment: Why not? I am sorry if i am any causing trouble. ( I new to this Linux community).

Comment: Because it clutters the board and ultimately helps no one.

Comment: oh ok i see. I am sorry. I´ll give it some then, thanks.

Comment: May you should go more in detail ... 'I've tried alsamixer' isn't very helpful. What have you done? f.ex. it is possible there are more than one soundcard in your laptop (the internal and a Nvidia?). Try `cat /proc/asound/cards` to see how many cards are listed. And try `alsamixer -d hw:2` to configure the card with the index (first number in the list) 2 ... Then there are different levelmeter and switches. They are different from soundcard to soundcard. Which one are you using? And what is the effect?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was stuck in the same question/ issue and use every solutions online. I got the white noise/static noise by installing Ubuntu 21.10 MATE on ASUS ROG G14. However by some old posts none of them solve my problem. Including editing the alsa-base:

`sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

editing `/etc/pulse/default.pa`

```
load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0
load-module module-echo-cancel source_name=logitechsource
```

Applying this solution:

```
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x500 0x1b
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x477 0x4a4b
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x500 0xf
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x477 0x74
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x500 0x1b
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x477 0x4a4b
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x500 0xf
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x477 0x74
```

In the end this noise goes away by this procedure:

1. `sudo apt purge pulseaudio* alsa-*`
2. `rm -fr .config/pulse`, also I do this for sure: `rm -r ~/.config/tenacity/ ~/.config/smplayer/ ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/obs-studio/ ~/.config/pavucontrol.ini`
3. `sudo apt install pulseaudio alsa-base`

After the first reboot I confirm there is no more noise. and after second reboot the noise is avoided as well.

I highly believe it's the problem from the pulseaudio becauseI never got this problem on Windows 10, and the noise will also go into the audio-recording under linux. Also the noise show up on Fedora 35 as well. FYI.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1203240)

Comment: Yes but that was my solution (to remove .config files). There is no new question since I also solve the static noise issue.

Comment: Alright, I get it.